# How do I get rid of the "all-sided" grass block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I just logged onto minecraft and the grass blocks are really strange. All the sides of the block except for the bottom are the top of the grass block's texture. I do have optifine, so I feel like I might have accidentally flipped a switch, or something else. [image]

Answer (score 4):

You can switch the better grass option at Optifine's Settings, found in-game.

Comment: Which section is it in?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/202653/how-to-optimize-optifine-for-a-smooth-minecraft-experience/ This page states the setting would be under "Details".

Answer (score 3):

Go to Pause Menu → Options → Video Settings → Quality and set 'Better Grass' to 'Off'.